# Pine Script: Getting chart information of two different symbols in one chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a chart with two different symbols e.g. first symbol EURUSD and second symbol GBPUSD, to compare both.

Now I want to write an indicator and access the chart information of both symbols/currency pair.
With `SYMINFO` I can get access to the information of the main symbol EURUSD and can read `syminfo.ticker`, etc..

Is is also possible to access the information of the second symbol GBPUSD to read the ticker or other chart information?
The second symbol is not fixed and can be changed in the chart or add a third symbol e.g. AUDUSD.

I couldn't find anything in the API.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] your question to add a small code sample of what you currently have? That makes it easier for us to help you. This is called a [mre].

Comment: there is info that you need: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `request.security()` function where you can pass different tickers.

Since you mentioned that the other ticker is not fixed, you need to use `input.symbol()` to get the other ticker id from the user.

```
in_sym = input.symbol("", "Ticker")
sym_close = request.security(in_sym, timeframe.period, close)
plot(sym_close)
```